# Recursive conditional definition including summation in Haskell

Tags: haskell, recursion, sum

In Haskell, I want to define a function recursively and using summation there, what I have is this:

```
partitions n m l = gfunct n m l
       where
       gfunct n m l
         | n == 0 && m == 0 = 0
         | n < m  || m == 0 = 1
         | otherwise        = -- here the Summation
```

This summation shall be an implementation of what one would write in maths like

[image]

As far as I understand Haskell should support that style of programming.

(I am a confused newbie in Haskell, and I mostly seek for the solution and not so much to dig deep in functional programming)  I have tried out implementing it with `fold` or `scan` but I always failed.

Comment: If you've written some code that doesn't work, include it in your question and include any errors you get.

Comment: So you have $g(n,k,m) = \sum_{h=0}^n \operatornane{gfunct}(n-h,m-1,h-1)$ when $m\ge n$ and $k\ne 0$?

Comment: @DanRobertson: I have confused two functions while copying, sorry, I have corrected it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to sum something for $h$ from 0 to $n$ then you can just write that:

```
sum [ gfunct (n-h) (m-1) (h-1) | h <- [0..n] ]
```

Comment: This works perfectly, I am surprised that it is that simple! Thank you very much.